# Extract unique characters from cells containing comma separated text

Tags: excel

I have a list of cells with values like the below:

```
a,a,b,c,d
f,g,h,h,h,j
a,b,b
f,f,f,y,y,u,u
```

I want a formula that will give me the below (unique list of above). I should be able to write it for one row and copy it down.

```
a,b,c,d
f,g,h,j
a,b
f,y,u
```

Comment: What in the max length of your values in a single  row?

Comment: Max would be around 15-20 values. Each is a code that is about 25 alphanumeric characters

Comment: Given any thought of using User Defined Function? Small function will be helpful.

Comment: Do the results have to be entered into a single cell, comma-separated? If so, you will need VBA. If not, and you are happy with each result being in its own cell, i.e. occupying successive columns to the right of each entry, then this is doable using worksheet formulas alone (though necessarily more complex than a VBA-based solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a formula that will return comma-separated unique results into one cell, using only the built-in worksheet functions.

But, it is very simple to achieve the same thing with a User Defined Function (UDF).

Just place this small routine in a standard code module:

```
Public Function UniqueList(s)
    Dim i&, k$, v
    v = Split(s, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(v)
        If InStr(k, v(i)) = 0 Then k = k & "," & v(i)
    Next
    UniqueList = Mid$(k, 2)
End Function
```

If your source string is in cell A1 then in cell B1 enter this formula:

```
=UniqueList(A1)
```

That's it. Now copy the formula downward as far as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the repeated letters are in order, as in your sample, this should do the trick:

```
Function UniqueLetters(ByVal cell As Range) As String

    letters = Split(cell.Value, ",")
    For Each letter In letters
        If letter <> current_letter Then
            current_letter = letter
            unique_letters = unique_letters + letter + ","
        End If
    Next
    UniqueLetters = Left(unique_letters, Len(unique_letters) - 1)

End Function
```