# How to get unique value in single field of excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

How to get unique value in single field of excel?

example: I have field AS "A2" which contain the value as "MAH, MOP, MHD, MAH, MHD" , I want to get unique value AS (MAH, MOP, MHD) in same field i.e "A2"

Comment: use text to columns and split the string to multiple columns which are delimited by commas. Then remove the duplicates and then join it with commas

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar query resolved at stackoverflow.
Have a look at the following url.
Hopefully you should be able to resolve your problem with this.

[Extract unique characters from cells containing comma separated text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611887/extract-unique-characters-from-cells-containing-comma-separated-text)

Hope this Helps.